# how to get modified rows of a SharePoint Excel file to Power Automate Cloud Flow using the Excel Rest API or any other method other than macro files?

Tags: excel, rest, sharepoint, power-automate

I want to get modified rows from sharepoint excel to my power automate cloud flow. If we can get data of excel catch up events from a Rest API, That will easily solve my problem.(Please Refer the image attached for more info.) But I was unable to find a Rest API or Proper documentation for Excel File Rest APIs.
**Requirement:** I want to show the modified rows for approval.

[image]

Sharepoint Excel Rest APIs and version history.

Comment: I’m 99% sure that’s not possible. Happy to be proven wrong but not even PowerAutomate has a cell/range specific change event for an Excel workbook.

Comment: Yeah thanks @skin.  it's not possible via power automate.. That's why I'm tring to use Excel REST APIs. If anyone knows, please help me.

Comment: You've missed my point, if it existed, PA would have it is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to trigger a flow when a table is edited in Excel, & get those table edits, then this workaround may help: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/When-an-Excel-row-is-created-modified-or-deleted-workaround/td-p/2264670